# Ndepend CQL to find methods of certain types using particular framework assembly

Tags: ndepend

In order to check if types not derived from certain base classes are using a low-level framework assembly, the following query can be used.

```
SELECT TYPES WHERE IsDirectlyUsing "ASSEMBLY:Framework.Data"
AND !(DeriveFrom "App.BaseTypes.BusinessFacadeBase"
OR DeriveFrom "App.BaseTypes.BusinessComponentBase"
OR DeriveFrom "App.BaseTypes.DataAccessComponentBase")
```

Now I wish to drill down further to see which methods from those classes are actually doing so. But the thing is if I change the query target from TYPES to METHODS then **DeriveFrom** is not going to apply. How can these criteria be preserved?